# How to fix MySQL insert query in my Python script?

Tags: mysql, python-3.6

I am trying to insert some data in mysql using Python 3.6 but I am facing following error when I execute my query-

```
sql="Insert into log (merchant_id,products_count_before,products_count_after,feed_count_before,feed_count_after) values("+escape_str(merchant_id)+","+escape_str(products_count_before)+","+escape_str(products_count_after)+","+escape_str(feed_count_before)+","+feed_count_after+")"
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

My table structure is as below-

```
CREATE TABLE log (
 id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 merchant_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
 products_count_before INT(11) NULL,
 products_count_after INT(11) NULL,
 feed_count_before INT(11) NULL,
 feed_count_after INT(11) NULL,
 created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

My python function-

```
def upload_log_summery(self,merchant_id):
 sql="Insert into etl_log 
 (merchant_id,products_count_before,products_count_after,
 feed_count_before,feed_count_after) 
 values("+escape_str(merchant_id)+","+escape_str(products_count_before)
 +","
 + escape_str(products_count_after)+","+escape_str(feed_count_before)
 +","+feed_ count_after+")" self.connector.execute(sql, 
 [escape_str(merchant_id),escape_str(products_count_before),
 escape_str(products_count_after),escape_str(feed_count_before),
 escape_str(feed_count_after)])

def escape_str(string):
  return escape_string(str(string))
```

I tried to convert the fields into string but unable to solve the issue.
There must be something I am missing here but couldn't able to find out.

Comment: Hi this may be due to escape_string. Try first to convert your variable to string and then use escape_string...

Comment: I changed my code-sql="Insert into etl_log (merchant_id,products_count_before,products_count_after,feed_count_before,feed_count_after) values("+str(merchant_id)+","+str(products_count_before)+","+str(products_count_after)+","+str(feed_count_before)+","+str(feed_count_after)+")"
    self.connector.execute(sql,[merchant_id,products_count_before,products_count_after,feed_count_before,feed_count_after]) but it saying-TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Try to convert them once at a time apart from the sql statement and test their type to  know where the issue come from... In your sql statement you must use escape_string (str(yourvariable)) and not only str(yourvariable).